# Legend in R pch not filled

Tags: r, graphics, plot

Trying to plot a legend using pch, it is my understanding that these should be filled, but dont appear to be so. Is this a problem with windows graphics?

```
legend(36, 79,
    legend = c(expression("a"["a"]), expression("b"["b"]), expression("c"["c"])),
    pch = c(21, 8, 24), col = c(grey(0.1), grey(0.3), grey(0.5)),
    cex = 1.3, bty = "n"
)
```

[image]
would normally not be an issued but this is for a paper to be submitted and the legend and graphics in plot should match
thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (as for a paper to be submitted).

Comment: 21 and 24 requires fill and colour argument.

Comment: Use `pt.ch = "red"` or whatever color you prefer. You can also drop the quotation marks in the expressions and specify `col = grey(c(.1, .3, .5))`. Specifying `x = "topleft"` or similar is a lot easier than `x = 36, y = 79` too.

Comment: doesnt solve the problem sorry

Comment: Relevant post: [plot functions with filled point symbols and legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819762/plot-functions-with-filled-point-symbols-and-legend)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will need `pt.bg` argument to fill in:

See below example:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),
                 colour=rep(c("blue","green"),5),
                 background=rep(c("grey30", "grey70"),5),
                 shape=rep(c(21,24),5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#plot
plot(df$x,df$y,col=df$colour,bg=df$background,pch=df$shape,cex=2)
points(x=0.5,y=0.5,pch=8,col="red",cex=2)

#add legend, pt.bg is need to fill in the background of the shape
legend(0.01,0.5,
       legend = c(expression("LBM"["MR-AC"]),
                  expression("LBM"["Formula"]),
                  expression("LBM"["MR-AC corrected"])),
       pch = c(21,24,8),
       col = c("blue","green","red"),
       pt.bg = c("grey30","grey70"),
       cex=2)
```

[image]